# Azure rest api with Python

Tags: python, azure, request, azure-rest-api

I am new to Azure. I need to set up an automation script to list all Ips in azure using Azure Rest APi in Python. However i couldnt been able to get any result from the API url I am passing to the request.

I am following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/public-ip-addresses/list-all#code-try-0

In code block, I have tried using requests

```
import requests


apijson = requests.get("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/9540b342-9f94-4dd9-9eca-0698dda0107c/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses?api-version=2021-05-01"
```

I know I need to setup Oauth/authentication but I don't know what I need to declare or pass any token from my script

Answer (score 3):

> I know I need to setup Oauth/authentication but I don't know what I need to declare or pass any token from my script

You can declare/pass token, for example:

```
import sys
import requests
import json
import time

test_api_url = "Add URL which you want to test"


#function to obtain a new OAuth 2.0 token from the authentication server

def get_new_token():
    auth_server_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token'"
    client_id = 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
    client_secret = 'XXXX'

    token_req_payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

    token_response = requests.post(auth_server_url,
    data=token_req_payload, verify=False, allow_redirects=False,
    auth=(client_id, client_secret))
             
if token_response.status_code !=200:
            print("Failed to obtain token from the OAuth 2.0 server", file=sys.stderr)
            sys.exit(1)

            print("Successfuly obtained a new token")
            tokens = json.loads(token_response.text)
            return tokens['access_token']

token = get_new_token()

while True:

    api_call_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    api_call_response = requests.get(test_api_url, headers=api_call_headers, 
    verify+False)


if  api_call_response.status_code == 401:
    token = get_new_token()
else:
    print(api_call_response.text)

time.sleep(30)
```

You can refer to [How to authenticate and authorize Python applications on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate), [Azure AD Authentication Python Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244998/azure-ad-authentication-python-web-api) and [Protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory and API Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825145/protect-an-api-by-using-oauth-2-0-with-azure-active-directory-and-api-management)